# How to work with .net resource file for sharepoint project with multi language support

Tags: .net, resources, sharepoint-2010, language-packs

I am working with SharePoint resource file for SharePoint 2010 page.

Example:

```
<Field ID="{A1D46FA9-0AE7-421A-A714-9561631632E6}" Name="EYDocStatus" DisplayName="Status ID" Sealed="TRUE" Type="Choice">
    <CHOICES>
                <CHOICE>Completed Last</CHOICE>
    </CHOICES>
      </Field>
```

In the for Displayname and Choice I need to change as below

```
Display Name=**"$Resources:StatusID"** 
<CHOICE>**$Resources:CompletedLast**</CHOICE>
```

Also I need map this into resource file.

Name= StatusID
Value=Status ID

Like this I have 1000+ items to work. Need to suggestion to achieve this is in any automated way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resources - is a pain. Maybe some resource refactoring tool (for example this one http://resourcerefactoring.codeplex.com/) can help.

Comment: Yes, it works in VS2010.  It is available from Tools => Extention Manager => Online Gallery => Search => Resource Refactoring. I have an conflict on one of machines with Resharper refactor context menu action. Seems "Code Rush" extention do the same thing, but it looks heavy, and I have not used it.